# 80s-era computing experience in 2016?

Tags: pre-schooler, computer

I am of the opinion that modern computing technology is too good for kids--games graphics leave little to the imagination, things work more reliably and don't require troubleshooting, etc.--so I am hesitant to get a "kid-friendly" computer for my preschool-age kids.  On the other hand, I grew up with 80s-era technology, where cryptic error messages and primitive visualizations were *de rigueur*.  As a result, I think I am much more computer literate, since I had to debug BASIC code to get anything to work.

So, my question: has anyone recreated an 80s-era PC computing experience for their kids, short of buying a C-64 on eBay?  Mostly, I want to encourage use of command lines and requiring problem solving to get what you want done, not just tapping an icon.

(I realize this is somewhat akin to saying "You want to learn how to read?  Here's a printing press... have fun!"  Humor me.)

Comment: Yes. Linux box. I'm not sure how this is really a Parenting question so much as a general computing question -- you seem to have a goal in mind and a reason for it, and are simply looking for a technical solution?

Comment: Have you looked at https://scratch.mit.edu/?
It's a programming language developed by the MIT for kids to make their first steps in coding. It is not the command line, but might still teach your kids some problem solving/analytical thinking. Show them the Unix Shell later on.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about building a computer, not a question primarily about parenting.

Comment: Damn kids with their super user-friendly books these days. They should appreciate papyrus scolls just like we did when we were their age.

Comment: My opinion is that you can use modern tech to code old school style. It's just a matter of preferred syntax. Why couldn't you make a web based game in the style of c64? html, js, crude photoshop images or just vectors using colored boxes in css. hello world in all languages is pretty easy to grasp. I have seen some "teach kids programming" programs that seemed to skip the whole code part. Wasn't impressed

Comment: I don't think this should have been closed. This question isn't about building a computer. It's about whether or not older technology was more conducive to kids learning because of the imperfections, flaws, and limitations. I also perceive new technology to be a "gift from the gods" that kids can't ever possibly wrap their heads around without at least a high school level understanding.